# IIS hung requests - can't see CLR stacktraces in memory dump

Tags: asp.net, iis, windbg

ASP.NET WebAPI2 application on .NET 4.6.2, hosted on IIS on Windows Server 2016. From time to time, there is a lot (hundreds) of requests stuck for hours (despite the fact I have request timeout 60s set) with no CPU usage. So, I took the memory dump of w3wp process, along with `sos.dll`, `clr.dll` and `mscordacwks.dll` and all my project's dlls and pdbs from `bin` directory from server and used WinDbg as described in many blogs and tutorials. But, in all of them, they are able to directly see CLR stack by calling `~*e !clrstack`. I can see CLR stacktrace for some Redis and ApplicationInsights workers, but for all other managed threads I can see only:

`OS Thread Id: 0x1124 (3)
        Child SP               IP Call Site
GetFrameContext failed: 1
0000000000000000 0000000000000000`

`!dumpstack` for any of these gives just this:

`0:181> !dumpstack
OS Thread Id: 0x1754 (181)
Current frame: ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0x14
Child-SP         RetAddr          Caller, Callee
000000b942c7f6a0 00007fff33d63acf KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x8f, calling ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject
000000b942c7f740 00007fff253377a6 clr!CLRSemaphore::Wait+0x8a, calling kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx
000000b942c7f7b0 00007fff25335331 clr!GCCoop::GCCoop+0xe, calling clr!GetThread
000000b942c7f800 00007fff25337916 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::UnfairSemaphore::Wait+0xf1, calling clr!CLRSemaphore::Wait
000000b942c7f840 00007fff253378b1 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0x2d1, calling clr!ThreadpoolMgr::UnfairSemaphore::Wait
000000b942c7f8e0 00007fff253d952f clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x86
000000b942c7f9e0 00007fff253d950f clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x66, calling clr!_chkstk
000000b942c7fa20 00007fff37568364 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14, calling ntdll!LdrpDispatchUserCallTarget
000000b942c7fa50 00007fff3773e821 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21, calling ntdll!LdrpDispatchUserCallTarget`

So I have no idea, where to look for bug in my code.

(here is the full result:

https://gist.github.com/rouen-sk/eff11844557521de367fa9182cb94a82

and here is the results of `!threads`:

https://gist.github.com/rouen-sk/b61cba97a4d8300c08d6a8808c4bff6e)

What can I do? Google search for `GetFrameContext failed` gives nothing helpful.

Comment: Please open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and share the dumps with Microsoft. I don't expect you learn such a non-trivial technique merely via Google. Dump analysis, especial hang dumps, requires much more experience.

Comment: [analyze the dmp with Debug Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/how-to-use-debug-diagnostics-to-analyze-a-memory-dump) maybe it shows more details.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, this is not trivial, however you can find a case study of similar problem here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rodneyviana/2015/03/27/the-case-of-the-non-responsive-mvc-web-application/

In a nutshell:

- Download NetExt. It is the zip file here:
  https://github.com/rodneyviana/netext/tree/master/Binaries
- Open your dump and load NetExt
- Run !windex to index the heap
- Run !whttp -order -running to see a list of running requests
- If the requests contains thread number you can go to the thread to see what is happening
- If the requests contains --- instead of thread number, they are waiting a thread and this is a sign that some throttling is happening
- If it is a WCF service, run !wservice to see the services
- Run !wruntime to see runtime information
- Run !wapppool to see Application Pool information
- Run !wdae to list all errors
- ... And so it goes. When you do this again and again you will be able to spot issues easily